# Can't get "Sign In" link to work in Hartl's Rails Tutorial. Getting: No route matches [GET] "/signin_path"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

As the title says, I'm getting an the following error when clicking the "sign in" link when running my localhost app: No route matches [GET] "/signin_path"

Here's some relevant files/info:

When running rake routes:

```
        users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
        POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
   user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
        PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
        DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)       sessions#create
new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)   sessions#new
session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)   sessions#destroy
 signin        /signin(.:format)         sessions#new
signout DELETE /signout(.:format)        sessions#destroy
   root        /                         static_pages#home
 signup        /signup(.:format)         users#new
   help        /help(.:format)           static_pages#help
  about        /about(.:format)          static_pages#about
contact        /contact(.:format)        static_pages#contact
```

The config/routes file:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
resources :users
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new'
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete


root to: 'static_pages#home'

match '/signup', to: 'users#new'
match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
```

The header partial:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">  
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "Sample App", root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home",     root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help",     help_path %></li>
          <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                   <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign In",  'signin_path' %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Finally the sessesion_controller file:

class SessionsController < ApplicationController

```
def new
end

def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    sign_in user
    redirect_to user
  else
    flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination' 
    render 'new'
  end
end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your routes.rb to look like https://gist.github.com/dd6821926dc94e6587f8

Then change
`<li><%= link_to "Sign In",  'signin_path' %></li>`

to

`<li><%= link_to "Sign In",  signin_path %></li>`

Comment: Thank you!  As soon as I saw that I had the '' around signin_path I knew that was it.